# Adding custom buttons in Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Implemented an add-on for Firefox using java script.But i need to custom buttons in add-on for star and stop(Collecting and Sending click events to server).

Comment: What is it you are asking, exactly? What have you tried? Where have you failed?

Comment: Do you want the button to show in the toolbar of firefox? Like next to the urlbar?